# Closing Slack Modal from AWS Lambda after data submission

Tags: node.js, lambda, slack, slack-block-kit, slack-dialog

I'm having trouble closing a Slack Modal from an AWS Lambda in NodeJs(14.x), getting a "We had some trouble connecting. Try again?" message. I have read several alternatives about returning an empty 200 ok message, but nothing seems to work. Currently, my AWS Lambda return looks like this:

```
// Handle the Lambda function event
module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const handler = await awsLambdaReceiver.start();
    return handler(event, context, callback);
  }
```

Any idea what is wrong with it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed.

FYI after discussion with my cloud team we concluded that by nature a Slack app is incompatible with FaaS core concepts (can't guarantee a cold start + request processing in less than 3s). Moving the app to AWS EC2 seems much more reasonable (same range of prices, container always up) and allows repositioning the ack at the top of listeners like a standard Slack app.